# How to continue powershell script after child generated powershell scripts have finished?

Tags: powershell

I'm currently struggling with an issue and would appreciated any help or input.

I have a powershell script that, during it's execution, spawns other powershell scripts that run various commands. All of these generated powershell scripts exit automatically after their commands have been executed.

What I'm trying to do is that after all of these spawned powershell instances exited, run another command within the initial powershell script. Basically wait for all generated powershell instances to exit and then run a command.

Any ideas on how to implement that?

Thanks

Edit: The code that spawns the powershell scripts looks like this:

```bsh
foreach ($var in $filters){
    start-process powershell.exe -Verb Runas -argument "-nologo -noprofile -command .\$var"}
```

Comment: Look into [jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_jobs).

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert, but i'm not sure how those are going to help. The piece of code that spawns the powershell scripts looks like this foreach ($var in $filters){start-process powershell.exe -Verb Runas -argument "-nologo -noprofile -command .\$var"} Putting this in a ScriptBlock gives me an error

Comment: You should not put your code in a comment, put it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Wait-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/wait-process?view=powershell-7). Use the `-PassThru` switch to return the started processes. This should work:

```
$processes = foreach ($var in $filters) {
    Start-Process powershell.exe -PassThru -Verb RunAs -Arg "-nologo -noprofile -command .\$var"
}
# wait for processes to finish
$processes | Wait-Process
# now, run your other commands
# ...
```

You could also use [background jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_jobs?view=powershell-7) like this (using the [$PWD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#pwd) automatic variable):

```
# run all scripts as background jobs
$jobs = foreach ($var in $filters) {
    Start-Job -FilePath "$PWD\$var"
}
# wait for all jobs to finish
$jobs | Wait-Job
# now, run your other commands
# ...
```

or in a one-liner:

```
$filters | foreach { Start-Job -FilePath "$PWD\$_" } | Wait-Job
```

Comment: @stereoscopique Yes it works, but you should also consider if it's really the *best* solution and have a look at PowerShell Jobs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using powershell jobs as @jeorenmostert said

```
$j=$filters|%{
start-job -filepath "$($_)"
}
$j|wait-job
```

- here first iterate over the `$filters` using `%` alias of ForEach
- then start each job (`$_`) is the pipeline variable
- get them inside `$j` variable
- pipe `$j` jobs to `wait-job` to wait until the jobs has finished (you can pipe `receive-job` too to get passthru like results)